# Read old Swamp Thing issue about TV show filmed on plantation - I am sure I've seen it somewhere on TV

Tags: story-identification

I was recently reading an issue of Swamp Thing ([Vol.2 #41-42: "Southern Change"](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Swamp_Thing_Vol_2_41)) in which a company is making a TV show on a plantation where a slave had been brutally murdered. As they are filming this, actors start becoming slaves and masters due to dark magic. Violence ensues.

I am sure this was my first time reading this issue, but I recognised the plotline and I'm sure I've seen a near-identical story on a television program like *Dr Who* or *Love, Death and Robots* or something similar?

Where have I seen this before?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you asking to identify the TV show or the comic about it?  When would you have read this?

Comment: This is old Swamp Thing issue (from 80s). I believe this story was used elsewhere.

Comment: I got that much.  Do I understand correctly that you're looking for a _different_ TV show that used the same plot?  (And if so, are you sure you it wasn't a *Swamp Thing* episode based on the comic?)

Comment: @DavidW - The Swamp Thing issues that OP is referring to are #Vol2. #41-42 ("Southern Change") in which a TV company are making a docudrama about slavery; https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Swamp_Thing_Vol_2_41 - I'm pretty sure that they've not made this story into a televised episode or part of the cartoon series.

Comment: @Valorum yes, those are the ones. I am 100% sure I have not read the story before - yet I know I've seen it before, without any mention of Swamp Thing.